# Keystore configuration

Tags: spring-boot, keystore

I am trying to add a keystore

I have put the keystore file to project/config folder.

And while I am trying to reach via following app.yml, I am getting a null error.

Application.yml and build.gradle addition is below.

Application.yml

```
server:
  port: ${SERVER_PORT:8080}
  servlet:
    context-path: /flex-customer-service
  ssl:
    enabled: true
    trust-store: ${SERVER_PORT:classpath:/config/iba-kafka-test-truststore.jks}
    trust-store-password: ${PASSWORD:P@ss4TestKafka21}
spring:
  main:
    banner-mode: off
  application:
    name: flex-customer-service
  sleuth:
    sampler:
      probability: 1.0
    log:
      slf4j:
        whitelisted-mdc-keys: principal
        enabled: true
    baggage-keys: principal
```

Build.gradle

```
bootRun {
    jvmArgs = [ "-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=config/iba-kafka-test-truststore.jks", "-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=P@ss4TestKafka21"]
}


Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Could not load key store 'null'
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.SslConnectorCustomizer.configureSslKeyStore(SslConnectorCustomizer.java:128)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.SslConnectorCustomizer.configureSsl(SslConnectorCustomizer.java:88)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.SslConnectorCustomizer.customize(SslConnectorCustomizer.java:57)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.customizeSsl(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:338)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.customizeConnector(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:316)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:183)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:178)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:158)
    ... 9 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Resource location must not be null
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:201)
    at org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils.getURL(ResourceUtils.java:130)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.SslConnectorCustomizer.configureSslKeyStore(SslConnectorCustomizer.java:125)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the path configured wrong. It should be:

```
trust-store: classpath:/config/iba-kafka-test-truststore.jks
```